# error recovering pg_dump compressed file

Tags: postgresql, compression, pg-dump

I produced this backup:

```
pg_dump -v -Fc -Z5 -f thebackup.dmp.gz thedb
```

I can't open the dump with gzip, 7zip... I could recover the same files in the past without using -Fc parameter. Is it possible that using -Fc and -Z5 might have corrupted the compressed file?

Comment: Helpful article [here](https://dan.langille.org/2013/06/10/using-compression-with-postgresqls-pg_dump/).

Answer (score 2):

Just use [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html):

> pg_restore is a utility for restoring a PostgreSQL database from an
>   archive created by pg_dump in one of the non-plain-text formats

Using `-Z5 -Fc` on `pg_dump` does not transform the backup into a gzip format. It adjusts the compression level, but the structure of the file is still the specific **custom archive format** that non-database commands like gzip or 7zip don't know.

Comment: I used just plain -Z5 without the -Fc parameter in the past and I could recover backups in the past opening them with gzip. But this one slipped away. Thanks